# separating frontend and backend templates

Tags: templates, angularjs, express

Learning angularjs and want to combine it with express. After reading some tutorials and articles I'm a bit confused about templating, as both of them can have their own used separately.

In [this](https://github.com/msfrisbie/mean-stripdown) setup prepared for a tutorial there is a bit put it express (just some headers etc) and rest is angular. I think in a bigger project it may be a bit confusing when to use what template.

So the question is as follows: In such situation what stuff should I put into which template (backend provided by express, frontend by angular).

Answer (score 0):

The most standard pattern is to use Express solely to serve out and consume a JSON API, and to build all of of your user interface in Angular.